# Bundling a browser in my Java application

Tags: java, browser, cross-platform, bundle

I have created a Java app (deployed by Java Web Start) which needs to use a browser to display HTML5 content. Due to such browser not necessarily being on the user machine, I'm bundling a [portable version](http://crportable.sourceforge.net) of [Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org) in my JAR. This has two problems:

- The Jar is going to be almost 70 MB, Chromium taking up 64 MB.
- There doesn't seem to be an easy way of creating a communication channel between my app running in the background and the browser window, short of bundling a web server as well, like Jetty or Jibble.

The size of Jar isn't such a huge issue, unless it is way over 100 MB. However, the portable Chromium app seems to be windows only and I need to deploy on Mac OS desktops too. At the moment I'm launching Chromium in app mode (with `--app="http://..."`), because I just need a browser window with no interface.

So my question is, is there another browser I could bundle instead of portable chromium? Something that would preferably be lighter but it definitely **has to support HTML5**, and that I could control programatically from the Java background app (although a bundled webserver is a viable option, not sure how that would play with various firewalls). Maybe there is something lightweight and cross-platform based on WebKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX2 (this comes with Java 7) comes with a light weight html5 browser.

Comment: See [Adding HTML Content to JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) for more info.

Comment: That looks good, but I'm gonna hold off accepting your answer since I am hoping to target jre6 if I can.

Comment: I decided to use JavaFX2's Native Package and deploy an app with a bundled JRE so I can use this browser. Cheers.